# Is it bad design to have static and non-static versions of the same method

Tags: c++, design-patterns

The problem I am facing is connected with my logger library. I can create my own loggers, but at the same time, I want to be able to operate with a "default" or "global" logger.

So I figured that some of the methods of my logger class should have static versions which will be dealing with this "default" logger. That ultimately felt wrong in terms of design.

Here is an example of what I want to be doing

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<lwlog::logger> core_logger = std::make_shared<lwlog::logger>("LOGGER");  //creating some custom logger
core_logger->critical("A very critical message!"); //logging from some custom logger

lwlog::logger::critical("A very critical message!"); //logging from default logger
```

An example of my static and non-static versions of methods:

```cpp
class LWLOG logger
{
public:
    explicit logger(const std::string& name);
    ~logger();

    void set_name(const std::string& loggerName);
    void set_logLevel_visibility(log_level logLevel);
    void set_pattern(const std::string& pattern);

    void info(const std::string& message);
    void warning(const std::string& message);
    void error(const std::string& message);
    void critical(const std::string& message);
    void debug(const std::string& message);

    static void info(const std::string& message);
    static void warning(const std::string& message);
    static void error(const std::string& message);
    static void critical(const std::string& message);
    static void debug(const std::string& message);
};
```

Comment: This code doesn't even compile and even if you got it compiled by some modification it is confusing and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that would be very confusing.

A member function in a class performs a task. The task is described by the function's name, and (to some degree) whether it is `static`. Having two member functions with the same name but different `static`-ness that do two different things is completely unusable.

The standard committee knows this too, which is why [your proposed solution won't compile](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afb584fe1cdd0797).

If your users want to use a different kind of logger, they can do so at any time with a *different* instance.

You can provide one ready-instantiated in your namespace, so the user can do:

```
lwlog::default_logger->critical("Using the default logger for this one");
```

Comment: Yes, that is an option. The main reason this problem is boggling my mind is because the spdlog logger made it that way: ```spdlog::info("Use the new default logger");```

Comment: @Lightness what is wrong with using static function, could you also explain that?

Comment: @oblivion For one thing, [it does not work](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afb584fe1cdd0797). And if it did, it would be very confusing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit of course it doesn't compile, I meant just having the static version.

Comment: Just to clarify. This piece of code is just a simple example, didn't put it with the intention to compile.